# User directories for blog images

Tags: users, files

I am setting up a multi-blog site in Drupal. I'm currently learning Drupal and I'm a beginner. I am setting up Organic groups, to make blogs for groups. I have added CKEditor to get RTE in the text fields for the blog entries. I have also added IMCE to be able to upload images in the RTE.

Now my question is. How can I give each user an individual folder for uploading files? I don't want the users to access the full upload root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I had to assign a profile to my user role. Configuration>Media>IMCE. Create a profile with access to browse, upload, thumbnails, delete and resize for \users\user%uid. Atleast that worked for me.